# Haskell: How to create most generic function possible that applies a function to tuple items

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

This is a personal exercise to understand the limits of Haskell's type system a little better. I want to create the most generic function I can that applies some function to each entry in a 2 entry tuple eg:

```
applyToTuple fn (a,b) = (fn a, fn b)
```

I am trying to make this function work in each of the following cases:

```
(1) applyToTuple length ([1,2,3] "hello")
(2) applyToTuple show ((2 :: Double), 'c')
(3) applyToTuple (+5) (10 :: Int, 2.3 :: Float)
```

So for `length` the items in the pair must be `Foldable`, for show they must be instances of `Show` etc.

Using `RankNTypes` I can go some of the way, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
applyToTupleFixed :: (forall t1. f t1 -> c) -> (f a, f b) -> (c, c)
applyToTupleFixed fn (a,b) = (fn a, fn b)
```

This allows a function that can work on a general context `f` to be applied to items in that context. `(1)` works with this, but the tuple items in `(2)` and `(3)` have no context and so they don't work (and anyway, 3 would return different types). I could of course define a context to place items in eg:

```
data Sh a = Show a => Sh a
instance Show (Sh a) where show (Sh a) = show a

applyToTuple show (Sh (2 :: Double), Sh 'c')
```

to get other examples working. I am just wondering whether it is possible to define such a generic function in Haskell without having to wrap the items in the tuples or give applyToTuple a more specific type signature.

Comment: Look up `Bifunctor`, `Trifunctor` and so on.

Comment: Off the bat, my impression is that these take a function per tuple item (having looked at the tuple instance of it), which avoids the above issue. Please correct me if I'm wrong though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were pretty close with the last one, but you need to add constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
import Data.Proxy

both :: (c a, c b)
     => Proxy c
        -> (forall x. c x => x -> r)
        -> (a, b)
        -> (r, r)
both Proxy f (x, y) = (f x, f y)

demo :: (String, String)
demo = both (Proxy :: Proxy Show) show ('a', True)
```

The `Proxy` is necessary to pass the ambiguity check. I think this is because it wouldn't otherwise know which part of the constraint to use from the function.

In order to unify this with other cases, you need to allow empty constraints. It might be possible, but I'm not sure. You can't partially apply type families, which might make it a bit trickier.

This is a bit more flexible than I thought it would be though:

```
demo2 :: (Char, Char)
demo2 = both (Proxy :: Proxy ((~) Char)) id ('a', 'b')
```

I had no idea you could partially apply type equality until this moment, haha.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
demo3 :: (Int, Int)
demo3 = both (Proxy :: Proxy ((~) [a])) length ([1,2,3::Int], "hello")
```

For the particular case of lists though, we can use `IsList` from `GHC.Exts` to get this to work (`IsList` is usually used with the `OverloadedLists` extension, but we don't need that here):

```
demo3 :: (Int, Int)
demo3 = both (Proxy :: Proxy IsList) (length . toList) ([1,2,3], "hello")
```

Of course, the simplest (and even more general) solution is to use a function of type `(a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> (a, b) -> (a', b')` (like [`bimap` from `Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap) or [`(***)` from `Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-)) and just give it the same function twice:

```
λ> bimap length length ([1,2,3], "hello")
(3,5)
```

### Unifying all three examples from the question

Okay, after some more thought and coding, I figured out how to at least unify the three examples you gave into a single function. It's not the most intuitive thing maybe, but it seems to work. The trick is that, in addition to what we have above, we allow the function to give back two different result types (the elements of the resulting pair can be of different types) if we give the type system the following restriction:

> Both result types must have a relation to the corresponding input type given by a two-parameter type class (we can look at a one parameter type class as a logical predicate on a type and we can look at a two parameter type class as capturing a binary relation between two types).

This is necessary for something like `applyToTuple (+5) (10 :: Int, 2.3 :: Float)`, since it gives you back `(Int, Float)`.

With this, we get:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Data.Proxy

import GHC.Exts

both :: (c a, c b
        ,p a r1  -- p is a relation between a and r1
        ,p b r2  -- and also a relation between b and r2
        )
     => Proxy c
        -> Proxy p
        -> (forall r x. (c x, p x r) => x -> r) -- An input type x and a corresponding
                                                -- result type r are valid iff the p from
                                                -- before is a relation between x and r,
                                                -- where x is an instance of c
        -> (a, b)
        -> (r1, r2)
both Proxy Proxy f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

`Proxy p` represents our relation between the input and output types. Next, we define a convenience class (which, as far as I know, doesn't exist anywhere already):

```
class r ~ a => Constant a b r
instance Constant a b a      -- We restrict the first and the third type argument to
                             -- be the same
```

This lets us use `both` when the result type stays the same by partially applying `Constant` to the type we know it will be (I also didn't know you could partially apply type classes until now. I'm learning a lot for this answer, haha). For example, if we know that it will be `Int` in both results:

```
example1 :: (Int, Int)
example1 =
  both (Proxy :: Proxy IsList)         -- The argument must be an IsList instance
       (Proxy :: Proxy (Constant Int)) -- The result type must be Int
       (length . toList)
       ([1,2,3], "hello")
```

Likewise for your second test case:

```
example2 :: (String, String)
example2 =
  both (Proxy :: Proxy Show)              -- The argument must be a Show instance
       (Proxy :: Proxy (Constant String)) -- The result type must be String
       show
       ('a', True)
```

The third one is where it gets a bit more interesting:

```
example3 :: (Int, Float)
example3 =
  both (Proxy :: Proxy Num)  -- Constrain the the argument to be a Num instance
       (Proxy :: Proxy (~))  -- <- Tell the type system that the result type of
                             --    (+5) is the same as the argument type.
       (+5)
       (10 :: Int, 2.3 :: Float)
```

Our relation between input and output type here is actually only slightly more complex than the other two examples: instead of ignoring the first type in the relation, we say that the input and output types must be the same (which works since `(+5) :: Num a => a -> a`). In other words, in this particular case, our relation is the equality relation.

Comment: Thankyou, an interesting answer that gave me some more things to find out about :)

Comment: @jsdw Okay, it's a bit more complex, but I figured out how you might go about writing a function that works with all three examples in your question and I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into this. I did a bit of reading and ConstraintKinds look awesome. Essentially, constraints can be used as types and Proxy is a very simple data type (one liner) used to get those constraint types into a function so that we can use as constraints within it. Haskell you continue to bend my mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a function with a type

```
applyToTuple :: (a -> b) -> (c, d) -> (b, b)
```

where the compiler would check if `a`, `c`, and `d` are in the same typeclass. This is unfortunately not possible as far as I know (though there may be an extension for that somewhere). When you pass a function of a certain typeclass to another function, it's type becomes that of the first thing it is applied to (observation from GHC):

```
applyToTuple f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

has a derived type of `applyToTuple :: (t -> t1) -> (t, t) -> (t1, t1)`.
Testing it with `show` shows these results:

```
λ> applyToTuple show (8, 9)
("8","9")
λ> applyToTuple show (8, [8,9])

<interactive>:5:14:
    No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of `show'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 28 others
    In the first argument of `applyToTuple', namely `show'
    In the expression: applyToTuple show (8, [8, 9])
    In an equation for `it': it = applyToTuple show (8, [8, 9])

<interactive>:5:20:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from the literal `8'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t0])
    In the expression: 8
    In the second argument of `applyToTuple', namely `(8, [8, 9])'
    In the expression: applyToTuple show (8, [8, 9])

<interactive>:5:24:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal `8'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 8
    In the expression: [8, 9]
    In the second argument of `applyToTuple', namely `(8, [8, 9])'
```

You can, however do something like `applyToTuple' f1 f2 (x, y) = (f1 x, f2 y)`. I think you may be able to use [Template Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell) to transform that into what you want.