# Haskell: Function to apply some function to nested 2-tuples

Tags: haskell, type-families

Say I have a tuple like `('a',(1,("Hello",False))`. Just for fun (read: learning), I'd like to create a function that applies some function of the correct form to any such tuple and returns the result. Example usage:

```
applyFnToTuple ('o',('t','w')) $ \a b c -> [a,b,c] == "otw"
applyFnToTuple ('h','i') $ \a b -> [a,b] == "hi"
applyFnToTuple ("hello",('y','o')) $ \a b c -> a ++ [b,c]
```

I've done most of it as follows:

```
type family TupleFn ty out where
    TupleFn (a,b) output = a -> (TupleFn b output)
    TupleFn b output = b -> output

class ApplyFnToTuple a where
    applyFnToTuple :: a -> TupleFn a out -> out

instance ApplyFnToTuple b => ApplyFnToTuple (a,b) where
    applyFnToTuple (a,b) fn = applyFnToTuple b (fn a)

instance ApplyFnToTuple a where
    applyFnToTuple b fn = fn b
```

The sticking point is that last instance. I fully expect to need to add `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` since `a` is more general than the `(a,b)`. I also struggle to see exactly how GHC could resolve `a` and the correct version of my `TupleFn` class and know the correct type sig, but I can easily put that down to my own lack of understanding. But in any case, the actual error GHCI gives me is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> out’
                with actual type ‘TupleFn a out’
    Relevant bindings include
      fn :: TupleFn a out (bound at examples.hs:574:22)
      b :: a (bound at examples.hs:574:20)
      applyFnToTuple :: a -> TupleFn a out -> out
        (bound at examples.hs:574:5)
    The function ‘fn’ is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘TupleFn a out’ has none
    In the expression: fn b
    In an equation for ‘applyFnToTuple’: applyFnToTuple b fn = fn b
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

As far as I can see, no version of my TupleFn returns something with no arguments, so I don't really understand the error. However, I find it can be made to compile simply by changing the last instance to something more concrete eg:

```
instance ApplyFnToTuple Char where
    applyFnToTuple b fn = fn b
```

But that means I'd have to define lots of similar instances etc which is undesirable.

What I'd like to know is, is there a relatively easy way to make the more general version work, and why this particular error?

Thankyou :)

PS: I'm running GHC 7.10.1

Comment: Related: [How to create most generic function possible that applies a function to tuple items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220903/haskell-how-to-create-most-generic-function-possible-that-applies-a-function-to)

Comment: That's another of my questions. It involves a tuple but isn't really related ☺

Comment: Proposal: instead of `(a, (b, c))`, use `(a, (b, (c, ())))`. Then it is easy to write the instance `ApplyFnToTuple ()` which takes no arguments and returns output, and there is no danger of overlap.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a good idea. I originally avoided it but it is by far the easiest approach!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that *within* the definition of the `instance ApplyFnToTuple a`, there is no access to the information that `a` isn't a tuple - I guess GHC doesn't consider how the instance might be chosen in deciding whether it is correct as a definition.  This means it cannot know that `TupleFn` gives the right result to use, and so the instance doesn't typecheck.

To fix this, you can add an equational constraint to *tell* it that `TupleFn` is correct.  Unfortunately since the constraint has to mention the `out` type, this requires including it as an extra type parameter to the class.  At least, the following seems to work (tested with GHC 7.8 only):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances,
             MultiParamTypeClasses,
             OverlappingInstances #-}

type family TupleFn ty out where
    TupleFn (a,b) output = a -> (TupleFn b output)
    TupleFn b output = b -> output

class ApplyFnToTuple a out where
    applyFnToTuple :: a -> TupleFn a out -> out

instance ApplyFnToTuple b out => ApplyFnToTuple (a,b) out where
    applyFnToTuple (a,b) fn = applyFnToTuple b (fn a)

instance TupleFn a out ~ (a -> out) => ApplyFnToTuple a out where
    applyFnToTuple b fn = fn b
```

Answer (score 3):

As usual you can do this with singletons and type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

type family Tuple b as where
    Tuple b '[]       = b
    Tuple b (a ': as) = (b, Tuple a as)

type family Function as b where
    Function '[]       b = b
    Function (a ': as) b = a -> Function as b

data SingList as where
    SNil  :: SingList '[]
    SCons :: SingList as -> SingList (a ': as)

applyToTuple :: SingList as -> Tuple a as -> Function (a ': as) b -> b
applyToTuple  SNil       x      f = f x
applyToTuple (SCons as) (x, xs) f = applyToTuple as xs (f x)

main = do
    print $ applyToTuple (SCons (SCons SNil)) ('o',('t','w')) $ \a b c -> [a,b,c] == "otw"
    print $ applyToTuple (SCons SNil)         ('h','i') $ \a b -> [a,b] == "hi"
    print $ applyToTuple (SCons (SCons SNil)) ("hello",('y','o')) $ \a b c -> a ++ [b,c]
```

`Tuple a [b, c, d]` reduces to `(a, (b, (c, d)))`.

`Function [a, b, c, d] r` reduces to `a -> b -> c -> d -> r`.

Hence if `as == [b, c, d]`, then

```
Tuple a as -> Function (a ': as) r -> r
```

reduces to

```
(a, (b, (c, d))) -> (a -> b -> c -> d -> r) -> r
```

Answer (score 2):

## My eventual solution, for anyone finding this question:

As DanielWagner suggested, I ended up preferring the slightly tweaked formatting (using () at the end of a tuple chain to signify finish). This makes it pretty straightforward like so:

```
type family TupleFn ty out where
    TupleFn () output = output
    TupleFn (a,b) output = a -> (TupleFn b output)

class ApplyFnToTuple a where
    applyFnToTuple :: a -> TupleFn a out -> out

instance ApplyFnToTuple b => ApplyFnToTuple (a,b) where
    applyFnToTuple (a,b) fn = applyFnToTuple b (fn a)

instance ApplyFnToTuple () where
    applyFnToTuple _ fn = fn
```

and this can be used like:

```
applyFnToTuple ('a',('b',())) $ \a b -> [a,b] == "ab"
applyFnToTuple ("hello",(12,('r',()))) $ \h n r -> h ++ show n ++ [r] == "hello12r"
```

I expect the instances can be tweaked; these were just the first I tried that GHC liked :)

Ørjan Johansen's approach (see his answer) is a wee bit more complicated but delivers an even neater end case!

As a side note, where I have wanted to translate some structure into a corresponding function I've actually ended up just using my own data type for the extra power it gives me. The simplest form of that I can come up with (not using DataKinds for now) to use as an example is:

```
--using DataKinds these could be done slightly neater:
data Cons a b
data Nil

-- the list itself, where the type 'a' is built from the above tags
data MyList a where
    LCons :: itemty -> MyList a -> MyList (Cons itemty a)
    LNil  :: MyList Nil

-- this type family converts that type 'a' to a function signature.
type family MyListFn a output where
    MyListFn (Cons a b) output = a -> (MyListFn b output) 
    MyListFn Nil output = output

-- this function applies items in MyList a to a MyListFn a just
-- like we did with tuples. Note no type family, because
-- no type dependant differences in behaviour needed:
applyFnToMyList :: MyList a -> MyListFn a out -> out
applyFnToMyList (LCons a b) fn = applyFnToMyList b (fn a)
applyFnToMyList LNil fn = fn
```

with very similar usage as the tuple case:

```
applyFnToMyList (LCons 'a' (LCons 'b' LNil)) $ \a b -> [a,b] == "ab"
applyFnToMyList (LCons "hello" (LCons 12 (LCons 'r' LNil))) $ \h n r -> h ++ show n ++ [r] == "hello12r"
```

**TL;DR** You can create functions that apply a function of whatever parity required over some elements of a polymorphic data structure in a totally type safe way. Awesome stuff, Haskell!

Comment: I think you can simplify the instances by using plain `()` instead of `(a,())`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks; I made the relevant updates. I thought I tried that earlier to no avail but all seemed fine this time :)