# Type signature for function with possibly polymorphic arguments

Tags: haskell

Can I, and if so, how do I, write the type signature for a function:

```
g f x y = (f x, f y)
```

Such that given:

```
f1 :: a -> [a]
f1 x = [x]

x1 :: Int
x1 = 42

c1 :: Char
c1 = 'c'

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x = 3 * x

x2 :: Int
x2 = 5
```

Such that:

```
g f1 x1 c1 == ([42], ['c']) :: ([Int], [Char])
g f2 x1 x2 == (126, 15) :: (Int, Int)
```

Comment: as  @ErikR showed you in his (now deleted) answer the left-hand side is doable but the type on the rhs depends on the type of `f` so I guess you would need to use type-families as well - if this is all-right for you than it should be possible - of course this is only a guess - for all I know there is a way to express this ;)

Comment: Happy to use GHC extensions

Comment: @user3237465: on a quick glance (at least your simple version) I think you would run into trouble with `f2` as this is not *forall a* but just for `Int` any longer

Comment: @Carsten, type families will not help you; neither a "pattern" nor a result of a type family can be quantified. Class instances can't be either, so I'm pretty sure this whole thing is impossible.

Comment: @dfeuer yes you are right sorry - it's an interesting problem - indeed I thought I could easily shoot Idris at it by I'm ending with a "SCOPE ERROR" and am trying to figure out if this is an bug or if I am stupid: https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/c6ed79f8c57eae2d1af55525ee089c88 - anyone able to enlighten me?

Comment: If this is possible at all it would require [impredicative types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Impredicative_types) and that way lies madness. Even with `ImpredicativeTypes` I don't think you can put a `forall` in the head of a class instance.

Comment: never mind my question ... I'm obviously stupid

Answer (score 15):

No, you can't. The basic problem is that Haskell's syntax has fooled you into thinking that `f1`'s and `f2`'s types are more similar than they really are. Once translated into GHC Core, they look rather more different:

```
f1 :: forall a . a -> [a]
f2 :: Int -> Int
```

Not only this, but the corresponding *terms* look rather different:

```
f1 = Λa -> λ(x :: a) -> [x]
f2 = λ(x :: Int) -> 3 * x
```

As you can see, `f1` and `f2` actually have *different numbers of arguments*, where `f1` takes a *type* and a *value*, and `f2` takes just a value.

In more usual circumstances, when you plop `f1` into a context expecting a function of type, say, `Int -> [Int]`, GHC will apply `f1` to the necessary type for you (i.e., instantiate `f1` to a specific type), and all will be well. For example, if you have

```
g :: (Int -> [Int]) -> Bool
```

and you apply `g` to `f1`, GHC will actually compile that to

```
g (f1 @Int)
```

But here you want polymorphism over whether that instantiation happens or not, which GHC doesn't support (I think it would be a rather radical and destructive change to the core language).

Since class instances, type family patterns, and type family results cannot be quantified, I'm pretty confident there is no way whatsoever to get what you want.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually possible, if you don't mind adding a `Proxy` argument, using a variation on [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223058/2476735).

Most of my explanation from that answer holds here, but we need to expand on it slightly by adding a couple more helper type classes (what I'm calling `List` and `Both` here):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds       #-}

import           Data.Proxy

f1 :: a -> [a]
f1 x = [x]

x1 :: Int
x1 = 42

c1 :: Char
c1 = 'c'

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x = 3 * x

x2 :: Int
x2 = 5

class b ~ [a] => List a b
instance List a [a]

class (a ~ b, b ~ c) => Both a b c
instance Both a a a

g :: (c a r1, c b r2) =>
      Proxy c -> (forall x r. c x r => x -> r) -> a -> b -> (r1, r2)
g _ f x y = (f x, f y)
```

This allows us to do

```
ghci> g (Proxy :: Proxy List) f1 x1 c1
([42],"c")
ghci> g (Proxy :: Proxy (Both Int)) f2 x1 x2
(126,15)
```

`List` and `Both` are not the best names (especially `List`), so you might want to come up with better ones if you do use this (although I'm not sure I would suggest doing this sort of type trickery in production code anyway, unless you have a *really* good reason).