# Functions on pairs of different types

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to define "`pairmap`" like the following:

```
pairmap f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

So that the following works:

```
pairmap (+2) (1::Int, 2::Float)
pairmap succ (1::Int, 'a')
pairmap Just ('a', True)
```

etc.

Naturally, in the first case, both the elements must be of class `Num`, and in the second case, both of class `Enum`. In the third case however, there's no restriction required.

**Answer (but could be improved)**

The following code [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/moxzT6) solves the problem, but note that my functions have to be wrapped in a datatype that encapsulates both the relation between the input and output types and also any constraints on the input type. This works but there's a bit of boilerplate. It would be nice if I could use a bit less boilerplate to achieve this, so any answer would be appreciated (although this solution is reasonably fine for my purposes).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Function f where
  type Constraints f a :: Constraint
  type instance Constraints f a = ()
  type Result f a
  type instance Result f a = a
  applyFunc :: (Constraints f a) => f -> a -> Result f a

pairmap :: 
  (Function f, Constraints f a, Constraints f b) => 
  f -> (a, b) -> (Result f a, Result f b)
pairmap f (x,y) = (applyFunc f x, applyFunc f y)

data NumFunc where
  NumFunc :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> NumFunc

instance Function NumFunc where
  type Constraints NumFunc a = (Num a)
  applyFunc (NumFunc f) = f

data EnumFunc where
  EnumFunc :: (forall a. Enum a => a -> a) -> EnumFunc

instance Function EnumFunc where
  type Constraints EnumFunc a = (Enum a)
  applyFunc (EnumFunc f) = f

data MaybeFunc where
  MaybeFunc :: (forall a. a -> Maybe a) -> MaybeFunc

instance Function MaybeFunc where
  type Result MaybeFunc a = Maybe a
  applyFunc (MaybeFunc f) = f

y1 = pairmap (NumFunc (+2)) (1::Int, 2::Float)
y2 = pairmap (EnumFunc succ) (1::Int, 'a')
y3 = pairmap (MaybeFunc Just) ('a', True)

main = do
  print y1
  print y2
  print y3
```

**Answer 2**

I think this is better and more flexible [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/wMMtMi), but again, any improvements to reduce the boilerplate welcome:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data Func (c :: (* -> * -> Constraint)) where
  Func :: (forall a b. c a b => a -> b) -> Func c

class (c a, a ~ b) => BasicConstraint c a b
instance (c a, a ~ b) => BasicConstraint c a b

numFunc = Func @(BasicConstraint Num)
enumFunc = Func @(BasicConstraint Enum)

class (c a, t a ~ b) => NewtypeConstraint c t a b
instance (c a, t a ~ b) => NewtypeConstraint c t a b

class EmptyConstraint a
instance EmptyConstraint a

maybeFunc = Func @(NewtypeConstraint EmptyConstraint Maybe)

applyFunc :: Func c -> (forall a b. c a b => a -> b)
applyFunc (Func f) = f

pairmap :: (c a a', c b b') => Func c -> (a, b) -> (a', b')
pairmap f (x,y) = (applyFunc f x, applyFunc f y)

main = do
  print $ pairmap (numFunc (+2)) (1::Int, 2::Float)
  print $ pairmap (enumFunc succ) (1::Int, 'a')
  print $ pairmap (maybeFunc Just) ('a', True)
```

Comment: I don't think so, sorry. Is this serving another goal? If so, you should talk about it; there may be another way to achieve it than via this route.

Comment: Yes, I want to apply a function to a heterogeneous list, but I thought this would be a simpler example.

Answer (score 7):

The first two of your examples are somewhat simpler to generalize than the third.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

pairmap :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) d e. (c d, c e) =>
              (forall a. (c a) => a -> a) -> (d,e) -> (d,e)
pairmap f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

The caveat with this solution is that you need to explicitly instantiate the constraint you are using:

```
ghci> pairmap @Num (+1) (1 :: Int, 1.0 :: Float)
(2,2.0)
```

As for the third, here is a half solutions. If the second type is always a type parametrized over the first (like `f a`), then you can do the same thing as above (albeit your first examples cease to work - you could make them work by wrapping them in `Identity`).

```
pairmap' :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) f d e. (c d, c e) =>
              (forall a. (c a) => a -> f a) -> (d,e) -> (f d,f e)
pairmap' f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

And again, at GHCi

```
ghci> pairmap' @Num (Just . (+1)) (1 :: Int , 1.0 :: Float)
(Just 2,Just 2.0)
```

Comment: You might be able to generalize to that third one, and "unify" all three of them, using things from a couple answers I gave a little while back, regarding similar problems: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603014/type-signature-for-function-with-possibly-polymorphic-arguments/38606908#38606908), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31223058/2476735)

Comment: @DavidYoung Oh sure. I would prefer to stay away from a typeclass-dependent approach though.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion of course, but I would say my approach isn't *that* type class dependent (I'm not putting `pairmap` into a type class at least). I'm just using empty type classes to make type level functions (unless of course that's what you mean by typeclass-dependent). What I had in mind was something like [this](https://gist.github.com/roboguy13/045839a354bd8b89ec70c18cde781ad6). I would use type families, but sadly while you can partially apply type classes, you can't partially apply type families.

Comment: @Alec why do you need that `Constraint` in function? Why not just `pairmap :: (forall a . a -> a) -> (x, y) -> (x, y); pairmap f (x, y) = (f x, f y)`?

Comment: @Shersh because `(+2)` does not have type `forall a. a -> a`, it has a type `Num a => a -> a`. Usage of `Constraint` in the answer solves this issue in a general manner.