# Is it possible to use a general function to get the second element of a tuple inside a tuple?

Tags: function, haskell, types, nested, tuples

Someone asked me this while working on an exercise about a function applying a function twice to something, and I thought it was interesting.

The idea is we should make the function twice, that takes a function and an input to it, and applies the function twice, e.g.

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f x = f ( f x )
```

The typing makes perfect sense in general.
Unfortunately, for the case of tuples in tuples and the function `fst` we might think it possible to use it on `((1,2),3)` but this is not possible because of the type of `twice`.

Is there a way to make something like this that works?

Comment: I found question which I think have answer you want, but I didn't understand it yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220903/haskell-how-to-create-most-generic-function-possible-that-applies-a-function-to

Comment: Yep, that's what's needed. Long story short, you can't do what you want in Haskell today (not counting brittle hacky things), since it doesn't support intersection types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your typing it is not possible because your `f = fst` is polymorphic and the two calls implicitly involve a different type. If we make the calls explicit, they become:

```
 fst @ (Int,Int) (fst @ ((Int,Int),Int) ((1,2),3))
```

It could be possible to use a different type for `twice`, requiring that the argument must be a polymorphic function. This requires `Rank2Types`:

```
twice' :: (forall a b . (a, b) -> a) -> ((a,b),c) -> a
twice' f x = f ( f x )
```

However, the function above is of limited use, since the only meaningful choice for `f` is `fst` -- there are no other terminating functions of type `(forall a b . (a, b) -> a)`.

It should be possible to use type classes as well, turning a few extensions on.

```
class C a where
   type Res a
   theF :: a -> Res a

instance C (a, b) where
   type Res (a, b) = a
   theF = fst

twiceC :: (C a, C (Res a)) => a -> Res (Res a)
twiceC x = theF (theF x)
```

Here, however, the function must be defined in the `instance`, instead of being passed as a parameter.

Comment: What if we try `twice' :: (forall a (b :: * -> *) . b a -> a) -> b (b a) -> a`? I'm trying it right now, but not sure it is possible.

Comment: @talex In dependently typed languages, something like that could work. In Haskell, however, `b` matches only (injective) type constructors, not arbitrary type-level functions. I.e. `b a` matches with `(Int, a)` but not with `(a, Int)`. Further your function would be impossible to call since there is no terminating function of type `forall a (b :: * -> *) . b a -> a`, since that would be able to map `Const () Void` to `Void`, so we would get `f (Const ()) :: Void`.