# Referential transparency of polymorphic functions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, rank-n-types

consider this implementation of `on`

```
on f g = curry $ (. bimap g g) $ uncurry f
```

What is it's type? GHC would say `(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c` and that's a good guess. But it misses the instance `on (+) toInteger`. Let's try to fix that (using `RankNTypes`, `KindSignatures`, `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `ConstraintKinds`):

```
on :: forall (co :: * -> Constraint) a1 a2 b c . 
      (co a1, co a2) => 
      (b -> b -> c) 
   -> (forall a . co a => a -> b)
   -> a1 -> a2 -> c
```

And that typechecks. But when we try

```
> :t (+) `on` toInteger
```

We get

```
• Couldn't match type ‘c’ with ‘Integer’
    ‘c’ is untouchable
      inside the constraints: co a
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 forall a. co a => a -> c
      at <interactive>:1:1-18
  ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the inferred type of it :: (co a1, co a2, Num c) => a1 -> a2 -> c
    at <interactive>:1:1
  Possible fix: add a type signature for ‘it’
  Expected type: a -> c
    Actual type: a -> Integer
• In the second argument of ‘on’, namely ‘toInteger’
  In the expression: (+) `on` toInteger
```

So what does that mean?

Comment: Not sure what the problem with the explicit type annotation is, but `:t on (+) Integer` seems to work fine without it.

Comment: The problem is that without the explicit annotation the type is not `(Integral a1, Integral a2) => a1 -> a2 -> Integer` but rather `Integral a => a -> a -> Integer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: How to create most generic function possible that applies a function to tuple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220903/haskell-how-to-create-most-generic-function-possible-that-applies-a-function-to)

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: Sorry, Haskell doesn't have the necessary feature (intersection types) for this to work in general. You can do hacks with type classes to make it work in some special cases though.