# How to exclude nonsensical types without relying on type inference?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-systems, unification

I've been working on a type validator for Javascript to enable gradual typing for a language that was originally designed for dynamic types.

Type validation means there is only type checking of terms with explicit type annotations but no inference. Unfortunately, such an approach is unsound, because it allows to type programs as the following:

```
foo :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c])
foo f xs ys = undefined
-- foo f xs ys = (f xs, f ys)

rev :: [d] -> [d]
rev xs = undefined
-- rev = foldl (flip (:)) []    

r = foo rev ['a', 'b'] [True, False]
```

This type checks, because type inference is bypassed. However, `r` has no value, because the function application requires a higher-ranked type. While Haskell terminates the program as soon as `r`'s evaluation is enforced, in Javascript such a program would be valid, even though my type validator should reject it.

My first idea was to analyze the type annotation and to check if function arguments are compatible with one of the other arguments, but such an approach feels off.

Is there a more principled way to rule such types out without relying on type inference?

Comment: Surely `foo f xs ys = (f xs, f ys)` should not validate, if you are not doing type inference, because `f` takes an argument of `[a]` and you are passing it `[b]` and `[c]` and we cannot unify those types because we are not doing inference?

Comment: *don't* rule them out. they are not nonsensical. originally Haskell ruled out the higher-ranking types because it has type erasure (I guess). you have no such problem. your `rev` is polymorphic, the run-time object representing it can carry around a pointer to the definition together with its (polymorphic) type, you can compile it on the spot I presume, what's the problem? do you even need compiling it anew at each concrete type, maybe it will just work, in JS?? does `rev` really need to know the types of elements in the array which it reverses, in JS?

Comment: regarding `undefined`, Haskell's `undefined` is much more like `error "is undefined"`, so *don't* use JS's `undefined` which is _not_ like that at all, as you've pointed out yourself. :)

Comment: i.e. since you annotate them all, why not allow higher-raking types, is what I'm saying I guess. I wonder what would happen if you treated *all* functional arguments as polymorphic, i.e. the types of all higher-order functions as higher-rank? your system is probably much more on the dynamic side anyway. (I'm just thinking out loud here).

Comment: @WillNess The algorithm is essentially based on Jones et al. _Type Inference for arbitrarily ranked types_, but I only needed certain aspects from the paper like application rule with explicit annotations and subsumption. It allows higher-ranked types if explicitly annotated, here in my notation: `(^a. [a] => [a]) => [b] => [c] => [[b], [c]]`.

Comment: Now this higher-ranked type in the wild from the original question scares me, because it seems to be unprincipled and to render the validator unsound (speaking about soundness in the context of side effectful JS is a bit silly, of course). But maybe sticking to much to the Haskell/static typing approach is my actual problem.

Comment: I got the impression that the type from the original q is based on the same underlying problem as `id :: a -> b; id x = x`. In Haskell this type is impossible due to inference, but with my type validator it is excepted. This particular case isn't harmful as far as I can tell, but ever since I stumbled upon it, I wasn't sure if I can assess all the implications of this property of my validator. But if I understand you correctly, both types cannot be compared meaningfully, because the former is kind of higher-ranked.

Comment: @WillNess By the way, the idea is to allow impredicative polymorphism as soon as the algorithm is more stable. since every term is annotated anyway.

Comment: I'm not anywhere near beginning to becoming an expert or anything on these things but IIRC what's unsound is the type _inference_ for the _un-annotated_ higher-rank types. since your types are all already given, all entities are annotated, there shouldn't be a problem, IIRC. ---- re `id :: a -> b` how's that a type of `id`? it's `id :: forall a. a -> a`. --- with the annotations present, Haskell happily derives `foo rev :: [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c])` BTW (for `foo :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c]) ; foo f xs ys = (f xs, f ys)`).

Comment: ah, missed that, as you've said, Haskell's inference would reject such type, sorry. why _wouldn't_ your validator reject it? you only check applications, not definitions, is that it? maybe keep `id :: a -> a` as a primitive, then `bar :: a -> b ; bar x = x = id x` wouldn't typecheck...

Comment: @WillNess Yes, I only check applications, not definitions. There is no inference from expressions to types, because this would make the validator incredible complex given JS's complicated syntax.

Comment: Is your goal to rule out all unsound programs, or just some of them (e.g., the "obvious" ones)?

Comment: I have to say there's a lot I don't understand about this question. Some examples: `forall a b c. ([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c])` and `forall b c. (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c])` are very different types, and neither matches the rest of the question's assertions. With the first type, it should not be possible to give `r` a type annotation that passes validation, violating your "this type checks" assertion. With the second type, `foo` should not pass validation. On the other hand, an unannotated `r` isn't subject to validation in the first place, so why are you 1/?

Comment: expecting the code as shown here to fail? Of *course* un-validated code can do unsound things. What does "type inference is bypassed and lazy evaluation kicks in" mean? Type checking/validation is done before any computation begins; lazy evaluation, if it happens at all, happens during the computation. How can the second possibly cause the first, when it happens later? What does "`r` has no value, because the function application requires a higher-ranked type" mean? Why should higher-rank types be in conflict with evaluation? Your claim "Haskell terminates the program as soon as `r`'s 2/?

Comment: evaluation is enforced", but that... isn't correct. Either it's terminated before evaluation begins at all, completely independently of whether `r`'s evaluation is enforced or not, or it runs to completion, even after `r`'s evaluation is enforced. So... after trying to mentally correct for all these incorrect assumptions/assertions, I'm left in a state where everything seems fine and sound (except where there is non-type-validated code, which can't be fixed), and unsure of what the question is at all. 3/3

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I am ambitious, i.e. the goal is soundness. However, this only works if there are no side effects (just as a policy, not a guarantee). The problem is that I can type the example from my original question with a higher-ranked type and it works as expected. But I can also type it without the explicit, nested universal quantifier and it is still accepted, because type checking is only performed for application not for definitions.

Comment: @DanielWagner Maybe my example is misleading. I abuse Haskell's type system to demonstrate what happens when you only check applications but no definitions (i.e. no inference from terms to types. The program type checks because there is nothing to infere. Otherwise it wouldn't type check, because the infered type wouldn't match the explicit annotation. This is exactly the problem with my valdidator. I can give it the right higher-ranked type and everything works as expected. But the rank-1 type is accpeted as well, although it shouldn't..

Comment: @scriptum Okay. So to paraphrase the question as I now understand it: your validator is buggy, because `foo :: forall a b c. ([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c]); foo f bs cs = (f bs, f cs)` passes validation even though it shouldn't. Right? If so, well... we can't help you debug a validator without seeing the code for it.

Comment: @DanielWagner No, I disagree. My problem is most definitely not caused by a simple bug, but it is a conceptual problem. Haskell exhibits the exact same behavior as soon as there is nothing there from which it can infere the most general type as demonstrated with the example.

Comment: @scriptum Can you show a minimal reproducing Haskell example demonstrating this conceptual problem? I note that in particular the code currently in the question does not appear to me to demonstrate any conceptual problem: `foo` does not pass GHC's type-checker with the commented implementation.

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220903/7509065

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried to answer my own question, but rather vaguely. Maybe this helps to clarify what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to rule out nonsensical type annotations without inferring from terms to types, because checking definitions is not part of my type validator (it is to hard considering JS' complex syntax).

What I cannot guarantee is that an explicit type annotation matches a given expression. However, I should be able to rule such type annotations out that have no inhabitants at all.

I don't have any experience with proof theory but I guess [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) comes close to what I need. Here is an attempt to apply it to the problem at hand:

```
([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c])

f: [a] -> [a]
x: [b]
y: [c]
------------
goal: ([b], [c])

apply f
----------
subgoal: [a]

ABORT
```

Maybe someone with more experience can tell, if I am on the right track.

Comment: after "apply `f`", to what is "subgoal: `[a]`" referring? the argument, or the result of the application? (because `fix f :: [a]`...).

Comment: BTW `foo :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> ([b], [c]); foo _f a b = (a,b)` typecheckes, so that type _is_ trivially 
 inhabited.

Comment: @WillNess subgoal refers to the argument.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, but this is what I meant with nonsensical type. This statement makes only sense as long as `_f` has no effect though. So I was wrong again. Anyway, I need to guide the unification algorithm by introducing explicit type equalities, kind of like with GADTs. This is what I'm trying this weekend. Thanks for your patience :D

Comment: (so, with `fix`, we don't need the argument).